# What can we say if we have a filter instead of an ultrafilter in Los's theorem?

Tags: logic, model-theory

**(Łoś's Theorem).** Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a  language, $\{\mathcal{M}_i\}_{i\in I}$ a collection of  $\mathcal{L}$-structures  and $\mathscr{U}$ an ultrafilter over $I$. Let $\phi(x_1\dots,x_n)$ be an $\mathcal{L}$-formula and $g_1,\dots, g_n \in \prod_{i\in I} M_i$. Then, $\mathcal{M}\models\phi([g_1]_{\mathscr{U}},\dots,[g_n]_{\mathscr{U}})$ if and only if  $\big\{i\in I : \mathcal{M}_i\models \phi(g_1(i),\dots,g_n(i))  \big\}\in \mathscr{U}$.

**Question.** Does Łoś's theorem hold if the  ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ was a filter over $I$? Why?

Comment: Think about how negation works in such a model. If it's not an ultrafilter, how do you guarantee that exactly one of some sentence or its negation is satisfied by the model in a way that depends on the $\mathcal{M}_i$?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thank you. I got it. If I understand correctly if we have a filter instead of an ultra filter then we have another theorem I think Feferman-Vaught's theorem. Am I right? Is the Feferman-Vaught theorem exactly the case where we have a filter?

Comment: You should read about Boolean-valued models. We can model the notion of "truth" using any Boolean algebra (although it might not work properly if the algebra is not complete). What you can get with a filter is a notion of truth which is not classical, in the sense that there are more truth values possible than just "true" and "false".

Answer (score 3):

If you copy the ultraproduct construction, but using a filter instead of an ultrafilter, you get what's called a [reduced product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_product). As noted in the comments, Łoś's theorem does not hold for reduced products - there are problems with negation and disjunction. However, there are various weaker versions of Łoś's theorem which hold for reduced products. You can find information on this in section 6.2 of *Model Theory* by Chang and Keisler. A few years ago, I tried to summarize this information in [an answer on this site](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198261/7062).

The weaker versions of Łoś's theorem I referred to above all try to explain when $\prod_{i\in I}A_i/F\models \varphi(a)$ implies or is implied by containment of the set $\{i\in I\mid A_i\models \varphi(a_i)\}$ in the filter $F$. This is the most obvious way to try to generalize Łoś's theorem to reduced products. But the Feferman-Vaught theorem allows you to determine in a more subtle way when formulas hold in direct products (and reduced products more generally, as explained nicely in section 6.3 of Chang and Keisler).

Explicitly, the Feferman-Vaught theorem gives, for every formula $\varphi(x)$, a sequence of formulas $\theta_1(x),\dots,\theta_k(x)$ and a monotonic formula $\sigma(y_1,\dots,y_k)$ in the language of Boolean algebras, such that if $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is an $I$-indexed family of structures and $F$ is a filter on $I$, and we set $||\theta_j(a)|| = \{i\in I\mid A_i\models \theta_j(a_i)\}\,/\,F \in \mathcal{P}(I)/F$, then $\prod_{i\in I}A_i/F\models \varphi(a)$ if and only if $\mathcal{P}(I)/F\models \sigma(||\theta_1(a)||,\dots,||\theta_k(a)||\}$.

This statement can actually be viewed as a generalization of Łoś's theorem: In the case that $F$ is an ultrafilter, we can take just one formula $\theta_1(x) = \varphi(x)$ and set the formula $\sigma(y)$ to be $y = \top$. Then the theorem states that $\prod_{i\in I} A_i/F \models \varphi(a)$ if and only if $\mathcal{P}(I)/F \models ||\varphi(a)|| = \top$ if and only if $\{i\in I\mid A_i\models \varphi(a_i)\}\in F$, which is Łoś's theorem.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your helpful answer. As far as I understood the general Feferman-Vaught theorem tells us not only about the special case of cartesian product but also about exactly what is called reduced product.

Comment: Ah, I may not know the most general form of this theorem then. Is your reference the original paper, or is it written up somewhere else?

Comment: I just looked at the original paper by Feferman and Vaught and also big Hodges book!

Comment: @Alice.H Hmm... I didn't find a nice statement of Feferman-Vaught in the case of reduced products explicitly in either of those sources. But it is explained quite clearly in Chang & Keisler. I've edited my answer, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex. In your updated answer, what is $\prod A_i/D$? Do you mean $\prod A_i/F$?

Comment: When you write $\prod A_i/F$ and $F$ is a filter that means we have a reduced product. For this reason I think the Feferman-Vaught is speaking about reduced product.

Comment: Could you please explain the structure of $\mathcal{P}/F$? What is the equivalence relation over the power set of $I$ reduced by a filter?

Comment: @Alice.H 1. Yes, that was a typo. I'll fix it now. 2. Yes, it's a reduced product. 3. Given any filter $F$ on a Boolean algebra $B$, you can form the quotient algebra $B/F$. The equivalence relation is $x\sim y$ iff $x\leftrightarrow y \in F$, and this is always a congruence.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the way in which maximality of the filter is used in the proof of Łoś's theorem. (BTW, the fact that it's spelled with Ł rather than with L is what tells you it's pronounced somewhat like the first syllable of "Washington".)

Suppose $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter.

If $\big\{i\in I : \mathcal{M}_i\models \phi(g_1(i),\dots,g_n(i))  \big\} \notin \mathscr{U}$ then $\big\{i\in I : \mathcal{M}_i \not\models \phi(g_1(i),\dots,g_n(i))  \big\} \in \mathscr{U}.$

In other words, if a set of indices fails to be a member of the ultrafilter, then its complement is a member. You can't do that if the filter is not maximal.