# Does Los's theorem hold for the filter $\{I\}$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

We know that $\{I\}$ is a filter over $I$.

I'd like to show that $Th(M^I / F) = Th(M)$ as a consequence of Los's theorem.

Now, Los's theorem does not work in general for filters. See:

[What can we say if we have a filter instead of an ultrafilter in Los's theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360534/what-can-we-say-if-we-have-a-filter-instead-of-an-ultrafilter-in-loss-theorem)

Does it work for the filter $\{I\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as $I$ has more than one element, the answer is **no** - consider what happens if we take the filtered power with respect to $\{I\}$ (which is just the usual Cartesian product) of a two-element structure, thinking in particular about the sentence $$\forall x,y,z(x=y\vee y=z\vee x=z).$$

Comment: is it possible to give a counterexample with an existential sentence (rather than universal)?

Comment: @user1868607 No, since existential sentences are upwards-preserved by all filter products: if $\varphi$ is existential, $F$ is a filter on $I$, and $(\mathfrak{M}_i)_{i\in I}$ is an appropriate family of structures, we get $$\{i: \mathfrak{M}_i\models\varphi\}\in F\quad\implies\quad \prod \mathfrak{M}_i/F\models \varphi$$ (just run the usual part of the proof of Los' theorem).